# Configuração de indentação do Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, indentação

Estou começando a programar *C#* no *VS* (se alguém conhecer um IDE melhor, agradeço) e ele tem uma peculiaridade que esta me irritando:
Eu uso a indentação de chaves da seguinte forma:

```
for(;;){
   //code
}
```

Mas o *VS*, quando se dá enter com as chaves juntas ( for(;;){} ), ele indenta elas automaticamente para

```
for(;;)
{
   //code
}
```

Agradeço se alguém souber me responder se tem como mudar para a primeira indentação citada e se tiver, me mostrar como.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vá em Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Formatting > New Lines:

[image: Options]

Marque ou desmarque as opções até obter o comportamento desejado.

Comment: Perfeito, consegui aqui, obrigado! <3